# Percentage of Column B based on Column A values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as such:

```
event_name     number_of_products
     A                 30
     A                 50
     A                 20
     B                 70
     B                 30
```

I'm trying to apply a row calculation, in order to arrive at a column of what percentage number_of_products represents for each event name, like so:

```
 event_name     number_of_products     percentage_of_event
     A                 30                      .33
     A                 20                      .22
     A                 40                      .44
     B                 70                      .7
     B                 30                      .3
```

For example, event_name = A had 30+20+40=90 number of products, therefore the row which has 30 products represents .33 or 33% of all products for event A.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions;

```
select event_name, number_of_products,
       number_of_products * 1.0 / sum(number_of_products) over (partition by event_name)
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can divide `number_of_products` by group sum calculating through `sum()over()` window function.

Schema and insert statements:

```
 create table yourtable (event_name varchar(10), number_of_products int);
 insert into yourtable values('A',                 30);
 insert into yourtable values('A',                 50);
 insert into yourtable values('A',                 20);
 insert into yourtable values('B',                 70);
 insert into yourtable values('B',                 30);
```

Query:

```
 select event_name,number_of_products,cast(number_of_products as float)/
 sum(number_of_products)over(partition by event_name)percentage_of_event
 from yourtable
 GO
```

Output:

| event_name | number_of_products | percentage_of_event |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 30 | 0.3 |
| A | 50 | 0.5 |
| A | 20 | 0.2 |
| B | 70 | 0.7 |
| B | 30 | 0.3 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2adde52f1ef7fa1dc96ad173b7db9f5a)*